# What is the EventDispatcher on a Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Session for?

Tags: c#, .net, session, bloomberg, event-dispatching

`Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Session` has a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Session(SessionOptions, Bloomberglp.Blpapi.EventHandler, EventDispatcher);
```

The `EventDispatcher` class looks like this:

```
public sealed class EventDispatcher
{
    public bool Start();
    public void Stop();
    public void Stop(EventDispatcher.StopOption stopOption);
    public void DispatcherThread();
    public int NumActiveThreads { get; }
    public enum StopOption { SYNC, ASYNC }
}
```

In code  I use it like:

```
Session session = new Session(sessionOptions, someEventHandler.Handle, new EventDispatcher(2));
```

Do I understand this correctly that this simply tells the `Session` instance to use the `dispatcher` when an event occurrs to delegate the `Event` to the provided `someEventHandler.Handle(Event, Session)` method?

What are the `Start();` `Stop();` and `DispatcherThread()` methods for?

The `EventDispatcher` is not documented anywhere so maybe someone has some experience with this.

Comment: I see how this could be useful: If you have two type of `Requests` (one is asking for `Bid`, `Ask` fields, the other one is returning portfolio information), then having just __one__ thread dispatching the `Response` would increase the latency for the small responses on the session.

Comment: in that case you can simply use 2 sessions (which is the recommended way in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have access to a Bloomberg Terminal, you should ask the Bloomberg Helpdesk.

Basically, what you're doing is not the 'recommended' approach - i.e. that which is demonstrated in the tutorials. In such an approach, you can simply use:

```
Session session = new Session(sessionOptions);
```

But it sounds like you've already got the documents... so why are you trying to use your own `EventDispatcher`?

Comment: That's the synchronous session scenario. But I need to use an asynchronous session instance for which there are two constructors. One takes the `SessionOptions` together with an `EventHandler` delegate. I know how that one works. I'm interested in the third one, described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `EvevtDispather` that you can create it manually with required number of threads then you can pass it for as many `Session` as you want. All of them will use your dispather to handle events. Otherwise every new `Session` will create its own event dispatcher internally with one thread. So if you have big amount of non-intensive sessions it's wise decision to create only one event dispather for them.